# Comments using Facebook Comment Plugin disappear after refresh

Tags: facebook, plugins, facebook-comments, social-media

I used the code generated on this page:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/

However, since my pages are dynamic I replaced this part:

```
<div class="fb-comments" data-href="http://example.com" data-width="470" data-num-posts="10"></div>
```

with...

```
<div class="fb-comments" data-href="http://www.mywebsite.com/index.php?a=[some dynamic name]" data-width="470" data-num-posts="10"></div>
```

When I try to post, the comment would show up but when I refresh the page, it would disappear. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your url has get parameters.

The facebook like button, the comments box, etc, they don't use the get parameters so for you having this:

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/index.php?a=[some dynamic name]
```

or this:

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/index.php
```

Its all the same

Comment: But how will I put the FB comments on dynamic pages? I mean, how to tag it as a different page? Is there a way?

Comment: Well you have to transform your urls into something like this http://www.mywebsite.com/index.php/dynamic_name, for example if you look at the stackoverflow's urls you'll see that they instead of using a get parameter for the id of the question, they use a uri segment